# Use project deploy token to access gitlab api

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to read some files in one project existing in **gitlab** from the application via **gitlab** API. I create `deploy token` in the project through

```
settings -> Repository -> Deploy Tokens.
```

I then try

```
/api/v4/projects/MY_ID?private_token=MY_TOKEN
```

and

```
/api/v4/projects/MY_ID?access_token=MY_TOKEN
```

, and none of them work - Both return `401`

Can't this `deploy token` use as an authentication token, and I have to create a new user to achieve it?

But the documentation describes that this `deploy token` is used for accessing this project, or?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a *Personal Access Token* not a Deploy Token. These are created from:

```
profile -> settings -> access tokens
```

And in the API request the ID you pass is the *Project ID*, eg:

```
curl "https://your-host/api/v4/projects/<project-id>?private_token=<your-private-token>"
```

To find the Project ID either go to the project page or query all projects you have access to, eg:

```
curl "https://your-host/api/v4/projects?private_token=<your-private-token>"
```

Cheers

S